# Checking if .pem certificate is installed

Tags: certificates

Is there a way to check if some certificate is installed or at least list the installed certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `/usr/share/ca-certificates` and sub-diretories.

The files you see there all have a `crt` extension but they are in PEM format. If you want to inspect one of them (assuming you are in Nautilus) right-click on it and select `open with View File`.

On the Command Line you would type `openssl x509 -in <nameOfCertFile.crt> -noout -text` to see the complete certificate.